# Be $(u_n)$ and $(v_n)$ two sequences of real numbers converging to zero.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

> Be $(u_n)$ and $(v_n)$ two successions of real numbers converging to zero.  Let's suppose
> that there is a number $M > 0$ such that: $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, |v_{0}| + |v_1| + \ldots |v_n| \leq M$.

> Show that: $\lim_{n -> \infty} u_{0}v_{n} + u_{1}v_{n-1}+ \ldots + u_{n}v_{0} = 0$

This is what I tried,
Prove:
We are gonna prove that $|u_{0}v_{n} + u_{1}v_{n-1}+ \ldots + u_{n}v_{0} - 0|< \epsilon $
so:
$|u_{0}v_{n} + u_{1}v_{n-1}+ \ldots + u_{n}v_{0}| \leq \sum_{k=0}^n|u_{k}v_{n-k}|$

but: $ \sum_{k=0}^n|u_{k}v_{n-k}| =  \sum_{k=0}^{n_{0}} |u_{k}||v_{n-k}| + \sum_{n_{0}+1}^n|u_{k}||v_{n-k}| $

then i can take:

$|v_{n}| + |v_{n-1}| + \ldots |v_{n-n_{0}}| + |v_{n-(n_{0}+1)}|+ \ldots + |v_{0}|\leq M$
therefore:

$|v_{n}| + |v_{n-1}| + \ldots |v_{n-n_{0}}| = \sum_{k=0}^{n_{0}}|v_{n-k}|\ \leq M $

on the other side, taking $n = n - (n_{0} +1)$:

$|v_{0}| + |v_1| + \ldots |v_{n -(n_{0}+1)}| = \sum_{k = n_{0}+1}^{n}|v_{n-k}| \leq M$

so, replacing:

$ \sum_{k=0}^n|u_{k}v_{n-k}| =  \sum_{k=0}^{n_{0}} |u_{k}||v_{n-k}| + \sum_{n_{0}+1}^n|u_{k}||v_{n-k}| \leq M( \sum_{k=0}^{n_{0}} |u_{k}| +  \sum_{n_{0}+1}^n|u_{k}|)$

and I'm stuck here; i thought, if the serie of $u_{k}$ were absl converged then i could put $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}  |u_{k}|< \epsilon / 2M$. But i couldn't find the convergence.

Maybe this is not the way, can someone tell me a hint of what can i do to solve this problem pls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose $N$ such that $|u_i| <\epsilon / M$ for $i \geq N$. $|\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n} u_iv_{n-i}|\leq |\sum\limits_{i=0}^{N} u_iv_{n-i}|+|\sum\limits_{i=N+1}^{n} u_iv_{n-i}|$ for $n >N$. Note that the second term does not exceed $\epsilon$ since $|u_i| <\epsilon / M$ for $n \geq N$. The forst term tends to $0$ as $ n \to \infty$. Hence $\lim \sup |\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n} u_iv_{n-i}| \leq 0+\epsilon =\epsilon$ whenever $n >N$.

Comment: thanks for your answer,I have a doubt: what that means the first part: $|u_i| <\epsilon / M$ for $n \geq N$? i think this means that for every $i = n$ the number $|u_{i}|< \epsilon /M$ right? and the next:  Why the first term tends to 0? I can't find the justification. Again Thanks for your help

Comment: @adysthemicstudent That was  a typo. I have corrected it.

Comment: thanks for that, to finish this. Can u tell answer the second question please, i can't see how to first term tends to $0$ when $n \to \infty$

Comment: @adysthemicstudent It is a finite sum and each term tends to $0$: $\lim_{n\to\infty} v_{n-i}=0$ for each $i$.